# Behind the scenes of Java's BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedinputstream

To start with, I understand the concept of buffering as a wrapper around, for instance, `FileInuptStream` to act as a temporary container for contents read(lets take read scenario) from an underlying stream, in this case - `FileInputStream`.

1. Say, there are 100 bytes to read from a stream(file as a source).
2. Without buffering, code(`read` method of `BufferedInputStream`) has to make 100 reads(one byte at a time).
3. With buffering, depending on buffer size, code makes <= 100 reads.
4. Lets assume buffer size to be 50.
5. So, the code reads the buffer(as a source) only twice to read the contents of a file.
6. Now, as the `FileInuptStream` is the ultimate source(though wrapped by `BufferedInputStream`) of data(file which contains 100 bytes), wouldn't it has to read 100 times to read 100 bytes? Though, the code calls `read` method of `BufferedInputStream` but, the call is passed to `read` method of `FileInuptStream` which needs to make 100 read calls. This is the point which I'm unable to comprehend.

IOW, though wrapped by a `BufferedInputStream`, the underlying streams(such as `FileInputStream`) still have to read one byte at a time. So, where is the benefit(not for the code which requires only two read calls to buffer but, to the application's performance) of buffering?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm making this as a follow-up 'edit' rather than 'comment' as I think its contextually better suits here and as a TL;DR for readers of chat between @Kayaman and me.

The [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) method of `BufferedInputStream` says(excerpt):

> As an additional convenience, it
>   attempts to read as many bytes as possible by repeatedly invoking the
>   read method of the underlying stream. This iterated read continues
>   until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> ```
> The specified number of bytes have been read,
> The read method of the underlying stream returns -1, indicating end-of-file, or
> The available method of the underlying stream returns zero, indicating that further input requests would block.
> ```

I digged into the code and found method call trace as under:

1. `BufferedInputStream` -> `read(byte b[])` As a I want to see buffering in action.
2. `BufferedInputStream` -> `read(byte b[], int off, int len)`
3. `BufferedInputStream` -> `read1(byte[] b, int off, int len)` - private
4. `FileInputStream` -
   read(byte b[], int off, int len)
5. `FileInputStream` -> `readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len)` - private and native. Method description from source code -

> Reads a subarray as a sequence of bytes.

Call to `read1`(#4, above mentioned) in `BufferedInputStream` is in an infinite `for` loop. It returns on conditions mentioned in above excerpt of `read` method description.

As I had mentioned in OP(#6), the call does seem to handle by an underlying stream which matches API method description and method call trace.

The question still remains, if native API call - `readBytes` of `FileInputStream` reads one byte at a time and create an array of those bytes to return?

Comment: This is amazing. The first thing I say is "FileInputStream doesn't have to read one byte at a time", the name of the method is `readBytes` with an **S** in the end indicating plural. Yet you still keep saying that it reads one byte at a time. Why is the discussion "Does it do this?" "No, it doesn't" "But...what if it does do this?".

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to indicate what things are wrong in your example logic. If you don't want it, I'll roll back the changes. Now it's just so completely wrong that maybe you're getting confused with the things *you've* written, which are just your wrong guesses.

Comment: 1. That's a method name, internally, it could make multiple reads(one byte at a time) to a file on hard disk and create an array to return. 2. I'm not guessing, I'm going as per API method description and source code digging.

Comment: If underlying streams(like FileInputStream) do provide bulk read/write(which are actually handled by native calls), then, correct me if wrong, `BufferedInputStream` is just a helper-like-object to manage in-memory contents. Otherwise, the code has to manage things like mark, reset or any other efficient mechanism by itself.

Comment: So **now** you finally got it!? You're acting under the assumptions that things are done 1 byte at a time, when all the mass media, filesystems and everything else handles things in blocks.

Comment: Well, at least we got closure for this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168370/discussion-between-san-and-kayaman).

Comment: Thanks much for your patience. The community is awesome because of guru's like you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The underlying streams(such as `FileInputStream`) still have to read
>   one byte at a time

Luckily no, that would be hugely inefficient. It allows the `BufferedInputStream` to make `read(byte[8192] buffer)` calls to the `FileInputStream` which will return a chunk of data.

If you then want to read a single byte (or not), it will efficiently be returned from `BufferedInputStream's` internal buffer instead of having to go down to the file level. So the `BI` is there to reduce the times we do actual reads from the filesystem, and when those are done, they're done in an efficient fashion even if the end user wanted to read just a few bytes.

It's quite clear from the code that `BufferedInputStream.read()` does **not** delegate directly to `UnderlyingStream.read()`, as that would bypass all the buffering.

```
public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
    if (pos >= count) {
        fill();
        if (pos >= count)
            return -1;
    }
    return getBufIfOpen()[pos++] & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: If `FileInputStream`(and its sibbling) is able to return chunks of data, what is the neccisity of buffering? As, retuned arrays are always in memory and can be dealt as we like.

Comment: Because if you do want to read one byte at a time, you don't want to perform 100 file system operations. You get them from the....BUFFER! Then you can read as much or as little as you want, knowing that the filesystem won't be hit unless more data is needed.

Comment: I understand that. What I meant was w.r.t your answer - It allows the `BufferedInputStream` to make read(byte[8192] buffer) calls to the `FileInputStream` _which will return a chunk of data_.

Comment: As you say, `FileInputStream` will return a chunk of data, then it's unclear as to why there is a necessity of `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: I explained that in my first comment here already. It's not about reading chunks, it's about minimizing calls to the underlying stream whether it's file, socket or whatever. Reading from a buffer is faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168311/discussion-between-san-and-kayaman).